# Change Data Capture Resourse; Scaling in mult-tenant environment

Tags: azure-data-factory, change-data-capture

I'm exploring using the CDC resource for our ETL. However at one DB per client, we have several hundred databases. With the feature still in preview, what attempts/thoughts are there concerning scaling in a multi-tenant environment?

Recognizing that the CDC feature may not be the best tool at this time, we are trying to reduce our report latency to allow for real-time reporting.

Comment: What is the requirement?

Comment: We'd be looking at being able to easily set up, and maintain, a CDC Resource per client database. Currently the stream doesn't seem to pass any parameters to a linked service so even if the source/target is dynamically determined, it's still stuck on default values. 
Provisioning hundreds of Factories programmatically might be possible, but  make maintenance unwieldy. A fully data controlled traditional pipeline could be done, but relying on triggers and cycling through hundreds of source/targets and latency for any individual client would increase.

Comment: What is the requirement?

Comment: Enable real-time reporting for our clients.  Current latency is around 20-30 minutes using SSIS packages run from SQL VMs.